# Mailx with multiple uuencode attachments and body

Tags: files, aix, mailx

I am sending multiple files using following line in my script

```
find . -type f -name "Sum*pdf*"|while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}"; done | mailx -s "North Bus Correction" $RECIP
```

Now I want to have body of mail as well with the attachments and I have tried the below one

```
(echo "Bus Correction";find . -type f -name "Sum*pdf*"|while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}"; done) | mailx -s "North Bus Correction" $RECIP
```

But I am getting only attachments not with body of mail. What is wrong in that please help me on this. I am using `AIX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow.... My trails were worked

```
(echo "Bus Correction" && find . -type f -name "Sum*pdf*"|while read name; do uuencode "$name" "${name##*/}"; done)| mailx -s "North Bus Correction" $RECIP
```

Comment: maybe you can give us some explanation ?

Comment: @Archemar Usually `&&` is used for merge two commands in the script, when i tried that it works, now i am getting mail with body and multiple attachments.

Answer (score 1):

You are also better off using `find`'s built-in executing facilities, no need for a while loop

```
(echo "Bus Correction" && find . -type f -name "Sum*pdf*" -exec \
  bash -c 'for f; do uuencode "$f" "${f##*/}"; done' _ {} + ) | 
 mailx -s "North Bus Correction" $RECIP
```