# Multiple html files in message body-mailx

Tags: email, sendmail, html, mailx

I'm using pandas to get csv to html

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import sys
import json
sys.stdout = open('output.html','wt')

df = pd.read_csv('users.csv')
print(df.to_html())
```

For another file i'm using same scrip just changing csv and html file name

I can send content of one html file as email body

```
mailx -s "The Subject is $( echo -e "\nContent-Type: text/html")" some@email < output.html
```

Is it possible to send those multiple html files in same email, not as attachments but in email body ?, so email body should be like this:

```
file1.csv

output.html content

file2.csv

output2.html content
.....................
```

Comment: please take a look this https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183309/72456

Comment: thanks, but that's not what i want-i need content of html file as email body,not attachment